# Fail to select with count, group by, order by and union in Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, group-by, sql-order-by, union

I have the following three tables:

```
theUser(*user_id*, user_name)
ichat(*message_id*, sender, receiver, send_time)
gchat(*message_id*, sender, receiver, send_time)
```

The only difference between ichat and gchat is that the `receiver` in ichat is user and it is group in `gchat`. But it doesn't effect in this question.

Now I'd like to find out the most active `n` users (the user name and corresponding number of messages sent), that means who appears most frequently in `sender`. And following is the code I have tried:

```
    SELECT COUNT(totalM.*) AS msge, u.name
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM gchat
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ichat) AS totalM
    JOIN theUser u ON totalM.sender=u.user_id
    GROUP BY totalM.sender
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

But got such an error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '*) AS msge, u.name.
```

Do you have any idea about it? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try `count(*)` instead of `count (totalM.*)` Count should be the same right? as it's a 1-1 relationship  I don't think the engine likes trying to count records on one side of a join. and your group by should match the non-aggregated column of the select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS msge, u.name
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM gchat
        UNION ALL
        SELECT * FROM ichat) AS totalM
    JOIN theUser u ON totalM.sender=u.user_id
    GROUP BY u.Name
    ORDER BY COUNT(*)
```

1. GROUP BY should match non-aggregated select columns
2. I believe the engine can't count one side of a table join.  It doesn't know the relationship is 1-1 or 1-M before it starts counting so it has to count both sides thus count(*).

Or you could just switch both count(*)'s to count(1) for the same effect I belive.

Comment: Thanks, it works! But why should it be `GROUP BY u.Name` rather than `totalM.sender`?

Comment: u.name is in the select.  totalm.sender isn't.  I know they net to the same value but you should group by what's in your select! (non-aggregated)

Comment: @user5779223 If you have multiple users with the same name, grouping by name will merge their counts; so you may still want to group by user_id|sender; however, if that is the case, there are only a few circumstances where you would not want to select the user_id as well.

Comment: nods @uuerrdo yes you are correct. user5779223, you may want to add u.name and user_ID to the select/group by if you have multiple users with same name.  Otherwise you can't tell one user from another if they have the same name and the counts.